# help calling an Intent / activity that has already been created

Tags: android

I have two buttons on my application. One button starts a new Game (lets say solitair).
When ever this button is pressed it will always start a new game

My problem is that I would like a second button to go back to the game that has already started if the user clicks back.

How do I go about recalling that activity that has already been created

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the state of the activity

`onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState()` are used to handle the activity state

**onSaveInstanceState()** method gets called for an activity when user leaves the activity. Note this method is only called when activity is present in the History state and user can come back to the activity.

**onRestoreInstanceState()** restores the state of the views.

see the following link

[How to manage activity state](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/tag/managing-activity-state/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the game is from a third party. As I see it you don't even need second button. Just click the first one again and you will get back to the game.
If the game intercepts `Back` it may intentionally destroy it's state so there is no way to jump back to the place that you were before hitting `Back`.

Comment: no the game is my own within the application. (game is just an example)

Comment: I see. You will have to follow the advise in the answer of Deepakkk then and make your game preserve its state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read [manual about activity stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html) 
Your application can has more than one task and more than one activity back stack